# Firefox Javascript stop error

Tags: javascript, firefox

When I run Firefox and open any website, after some time I am getting `JavaScript Stop and continue error`, and the page is getting hang up. Can anyone please help in resolve this?

Comment: Explain your error. The question isn't clear. Post the code causing the error.

Comment: Sorry its not the my code, its a general Browser error. Any website I open after some time, browser throws me an error, saying "JavaScript stop running, do you want to stop script or continue".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really have the problem on every page then much probably the issue is caused by your broken Firefox profile or some badly written addon/plugin you've installed. Reset your profile or disable/uninstall addons and plugins to see if it helps first.